# Why doesn't shell scripts in Shortcuts see my utilities?

Tags: macos, shortcut

i tried using shortcuts. i wanted to run scripts there, but i constantly get an error that the brew utility was not found. it feels like the scripts run in isolation.

i tried use

1. brew link php
2. eval 'brew link php'
3. sh fileWithMyScript.sh

and always got error. how to fix it?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `brew` command is not in macOS default `PATH`. You will either have to use the full path to the command or set `PATH` before calling the command:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew link php
PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin brew link php
PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin cd ~/utils && sh php_8.1.sh
```

Use a different directory than `/opt/homebrew/bin` if homebrew is installed elsewhere.